# User level categories

Tags: categories, login, exclude

I am using ClassiPress to create a different type of listing classifieds.

I will select manually who can subscribe or not (only a type of leaders for a religious institution).

I have four categories. Two of them need to be available to every one at all times (to browse). The four will be available to the leaders. The leaders will be able to post in all four categories, and they will be able to view / post all four categories. **But** the main public will only see two. How could I go about this?

I could make the two categories that need login, subjected to a php conditional line.

I saw a solution similar solution here [How to block a category from one user and enable the category for the rest of the users](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21558/how-to-block-a-category-from-one-user-and-enable-the-category-for-the-rest-of-the), but I do not have the same problem. Basically, every one without login is able to see two of the four categories, two always hidden for everyone, except teacher, who once logged in are able to see everything.

Any one?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried quite a few plug-ins to restrict user access. The best that I've found is the Members Plug-in by Justin Tadlock.

**You can download it here:**

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/

**Source:**

[WordPress as a CMS Membership website](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22191/wordpress-as-a-cms-membership-website)

The plug-in allows you to restrict access to individual posts, possibly by categories, but I don't see the setting after briefly looking.

**More detailed instructions can be found here:**

[WebTide Website, Members Plug-in Page](http://webtide.wordpress.com/2010/07/20/how-to-use-the-members-plugin-to-restrict-access-to-wordpress-3-0-custom-post-type/)